# cannot import name is_secure transport

Tags: python, twython, python-twitter

I tried to reinstall and reinstall three times, I tried to pip3 install --upgrade as well, simply no method I tried didn't worked. When I try to import twython or python twitter, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/user/Documents/Project Lib/python-twitter/twitter/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
from .api import Api                        # noqa
File "/home/user/Document/Project Lib/python-twitter/twitter/api.py", line 29, in <module>
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .oauth2_auth import OAuth2
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_auth.py", line 3, in <module>
from oauthlib.oauth2 import is_secure_transport
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_secure_transport'
```

ps: This only happens on Python3, on Python2x all works fine.

Comment: If you are on linux you need to be doing `sudo pip3 ...`, unless you are in a virtual environment

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining well, I used all the terminal commands with sudo